# Как вернуть список к значению по умолчания?

Tags: python

Имеется список следующего вида:

```
board = [':one:',':two:',':three:',
         ':four:',':five:',':six:',
         ':seven:',':eight:',':nine:']
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при манипуляции с ним, потом вернуть его к исходному значению?

Comment: Создай копию и изменяй ее

Comment: Какие манипуляции? Приведите пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Копия списка создаётся так

```
tmp_board = board.copy()
```

Или ещё десятком способов.

При изменении копии оригинал остается неизменным.

Если просто присвоить список новой переменной, то это не копия, а тот же список.